# Combining a while loop with an if statement difficulties

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
public static String convert(String str)
{
  if (str.equals("# "))
     System.out.println(" ");
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#+[^#]+)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

  while (matcher.find())
  {
     String str1 = matcher.group(1);
     if (str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length() == 0 || str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").matches("[\\s]+"))
        continue;
     int n = str1.length() - str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
     System.out.println("<h" + n + ">" + str1.substring(n) + "</h" + n + ">");
  }
  char carac;
  carac = str.charAt(0);
  if (carac >= 65 && carac <= 90)
  {
     System.out.println("<p>");
     System.out.println(str);
     System.out.println("</p>");
  }
  return ("");
}
```

How do I combine the `while(matcher.find` with this `if(carac>=` so I can get this output: < p> < h2> Decibel < /h2> < /p> for this input: ##Decibel??? (Instead of that, I get < h2> Decibel < /h2>. I'm making an algorithm in which "#" is recognized in the beginning of a sentence and turned into < h1> < /h1> or < hn>  depending on the number of # present. After that, the algorithm recognizes if there's a capital letter in the beginning of the sentence; if there is, it adds < p> < /p> at the beginning and end of the paragraph. 
The big problem I'm having, is that I want to be able to combine both. so let's say I would have #Appendix, I would like it to convert to < p> < h1> Appendix < /h1> < /p>

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to follow what this code is trying to achieve, which makes it much harder to answer the question. You've given us one example of what you're trying to achieve (which could never work with your current condition, given that `"<h2>Decibel</h2>"` doesn't start with a character between A and Z) but not a general aim.

Comment: I'm making an algorithm in which "#" is recognized in the beginning of a sentence and turned into < h1> < /h1> or < hn> </hn> depending on the number of # present. After that, the algorithm recognizes if there's a capital letter in the beginning of the sentence; if there is, it adds < p> </p> at the beginning and end of the paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public static String convert(String str)
 {
   if (str.equals("# "))
      System.out.println(" ");
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#+[^#]+)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

   while (matcher.find())
   {
       boolean append_p = false;
       char carac;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
       if(Character.isLetter(str.charAt((i)))){
           if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))
           {
              System.out.print("<p>");
              append_p = true;
              break;
           }
       }else{
           append_p = false;
       }
   }
      String str1 = matcher.group(1);
      if (str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length() == 0 || str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").matches("[\\s]+"))
         continue;
      int n = str1.length() - str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
      System.out.print("<h" + n + ">" + str1.substring(n) + "</h" + n + ">");
      if(append_p == true){ System.out.print("</p>"); append_p = false;}
   }
   if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(0)){
      System.out.println("<p>"+str+"</p>");
   return ("");
 }
```

this will test if the first character is an upper case letter and append/prepend `<p></p>`.

Comment: the # part already works perfectly. it's the < p> part I'm having troubles with

Comment: The big problem I'm having, is that I want to be able to combine both. so let's say I would have #Appendix, I would like it to convert to < p> < h1> Appendix < /h1> < /p>

Comment: @Arn0ld_t i saw some flaws in your code. Let me correct them and post the entire `convert()` source code for your current predicament of solving `<p><h1>Appendix</h1></p>`

Comment: @Arn0ld_t there, I have integrated the `if()` statement into your while loop.

Comment: that's great...but the <p> part only works with one #...it doesnt work when there are none or when there's more then one #

Comment: @Arn0ld_t now? I edited it to find the first Letter in your string and then see if its an upper case.

Comment: oh this is great! I have one last thing to ask you: if I want my algorithm to recognize lists: ie A paragraph starting with this: -Coliflower -radishes -carrots and replace the "-" by < li> < /li> at the beginning and end of each list item (while also doing the rest with the # and the paragraphs), how should i do that???

Comment: @Arn0ld_t like i said, you will need multiple matchers. Anyways I think that will solve your problem

Comment: I add another matcher inside the while loop?